# Dom4j: Node implementation incompatibility

Tags: java, xml, dom4j, incompatibility

Dom4j is obviously an awesome project, it hasn't been touched since 2005, yet it's still widely used.

However, the incompatibility of the Node implementations causes me some issues. There are name clashes between `org.dom4j`, `org.w3c.dom`, and other, e.g. `org.dom4j.Node` and `org.w3c.dom.Node`.

For instance, I have `<li><p>Some content</p></li>` and want to pull anything from `<p>` to `<li>` and get rid of `<p>`. So I tried

```
    if( itemElm.getFirstChild().getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE ){
        NodeList nodes = itemElm.getFirstChild().getChildNodes();
        //itemElm.removeChild( itemElm.getFirstChild() ); // No effect on error
        for( int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++ ) {
            itemElm.appendChild( nodes.item(i) );
        }
    }/**/
```

Which would work in other implementations I know from C++, .Net or even Java. But not with Dom4j:

```
// Cannot convert: org.dom4j.tree.DefaultText@275d595c [Text: "Some content."] into a W3C DOM Node
```

So I tried

```
itemElm.add( DOMNodeHelper.asDOMNode( itemElm, nodes.item(i) ));
```

Nope - the same. So I tried:

```
DOMNodeHelper.appendChild( itemElm, nodes.item(i) ); // TODO: Could improve Dom4j.
```

Because it's `appendChild(org.dom4j.Node, org.w3c.dom.Node)`. But no - same result.

**How should I solve this? How I am supposed to work with these two type sets in Dom4j?** Thanks.

*Context: http://code.google.com/p/jtexy/source/browse/trunk/core/src/main/java/cz/dynawest/jtexy/modules/ListModule.java#380*

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to work with the DOM api, there is absolutely no reason to use DOM4J; go with  latest xerces or the one provided by the JRE.

There may be reasons to use another API, such as DOM4J, but then only the "native" API should be used. I wouldn't trust the DOM adaptaion layer in DOM4J for any serious work; as you said, it hasn't been touched since 2005.

Comment: That's the problem - I use native api, but it leaks the W3C DOM types somewhere and expects Dom4j types elsewhere. With no obvious alternative.

Comment: What do you mean by 'leaks the W3C DOM types'? If you don't use anything from `org.dom4j.dom` package, you'll never see any W3C DOM types.

Comment: I see, maybe it's my app's code leaking the types :)  I'll check that.

Comment: Why does it have such impl bindings anyway? Is it trying to act like a facade for several DOM APIs, in the slf4j style?

Comment: DOM4J is close to being very good, but it falls short on being to much  convenience for it's own good; there are too many ways to do the same thing; and the founder, implementor, obviously lost focus when he was 90% done. It's ok, but if you use anything out on the edges you're on your own.